# How can we extract numbers one by one?

Tags: javascript

This is what I have tried so far:

```
function MakesingleDigits(num) {
    let result = '' 
    let arr = String(num)
    for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
      result = result * arr[i] 

    }
      return result
  }
```

Let's explain my thinking

```
let arr = String(num)
```

This is used to change a number to a string type. I want to extract digits one by one,
so I will be using `for` loop.

```
result = result * arr[i]
```

This calculates the result. My intention is that if I input num = 781,
then I want to get the product of all digits, i.e. `7*8*1`

How can I separate a number and extract all digits?

Comment: @WaisKamal It's not _"illegal"_ - `"" * "7"` won't throw an error), but `""` will be converted into zero hence `result` will always be zero

Comment: @Andreas Yeah right. i ever checked just returned '0'. but when i listen answer, it's just string. but.. what should do i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for number's digit multiplication? if so here is solution

```js
let num = 781;
let result = 1 ;
let digits = num.toString().split('');
let arr = digits.map(Number);
for (let i = 0, sum = 0; i < arr.length; result *= arr[i++]);
console.log(result);
```

the same thing can be achievable by your function like this

```
function MakesingleDigits(num) {
    let result = 1 ;
    let arr = String(num);
    for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++){
      result = result * (+arr.charAt(i));

    }
      return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your favor. i just founded. its was simple but i didnt xd.. i thought was hard.. my solution is result = result * Number(arr[i]). but your code is also nice!!! 
i will study your code also :) thank you for your favor :)

Comment: @Loolii But did you initialise `result` to `1`?